# Oracle: epoch date to date with CEST and CET

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I got a date like this '1302104376' stored with the italian timezone UTC+1. I need to convert it into the format DD:MM:YYYY HH:SS, but with timezione UTC + 0 (GMT). Does exists a function that does the work, paying attention to the daylight period ?

Thanks for your help
Simone

Comment: Can you explain how daylight saving comes into it?  When you say the data are stored in Italian timezone UTC+1 - do you mean literally UTC+1, or is it UTC+1 in winter and UTC in summer?  And when you convert to GMT, is that literally UTC or is it UTC in winter and UTC+1 in summer?  If your stored data is in "local" time, including daylight saving, then you have a headache because the mapping back onto UTC is not one-to-one - you have a repeated hour on the day when the clocks fall back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you close:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('19700101','YYYYMMDD') + 
                    (1302104376/(60*60*24)),'DD:MM:YYYY HH24:MI:SS') the_date 
       FROM dual;

THE_DATE
-------------------
06:04:2011 15:39:36

SQL>
```

You'll need to adjust your output accordingly for differences in timezones, DST, etc.

[This site](http://www.epochconverter.com/) is highly instructive regarding epoch dates.

Comment: How do I adjust this query for EST, since its giving me a 5 hour difference? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could build on the result from DCookie's answer and add a call to SYS_EXTRACT_UTC

http://psoug.org/snippet/TIMESTAMP-SYS_EXTRACT_UTC_616.htm

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions184.htm